# Windows Universal App how to make page topmost and without border

Tags: .net, win-universal-app

I'm totally new to Windows 10 Universal App development, in the old .NET for creating a fullscreen topmost form i just did:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
Me.topMost = true
```

But in the new Universal Windows App i cannot find nothing similar by using intellisense on the page that i created, how can i do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

To make your app full-screen, try using

```
ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreen();
```